# change the language of runtime permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

How to change the language of runtime permissions in android?

When I'm trying to change the language using

```
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
        conf.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

It changes the application language but the permissions for camera such dialogs showing in english only.

**Is there any way to change the permission dialog language?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the permission dialog language?

Have the user change their device language.

At most, your approach will change the language used by your app's process (though that may change on Android N). Any system-supplied UI, such as the permission dialog, will use the language chosen by the user for their device.

Comment: The application language was changed but the permission dialogues like for camera request permission it won't changed.It was showing in english only.

Comment: @krishnachaitanya: Correct. As I wrote in my answer, any system-supplied UI, such as the permission dialog, will use the language chosen by the user for their device. You cannot affect this.

Comment: The facebook app does this without having the user change the device language.  I.e. change the language in the facebook app to Chinese, then click on the photo chooser - you will be prompted for permissions (with a system dialog) in Chinese. So this answer does not seem correct.

Comment: @jt-gilkeson: Perhaps Facebook is exploiting some security flaw on that device.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to create your own dialog or change the language of your cell phone before or after changing the application language.

Comment: I didn't understand can we create custom dialog for runtime permissions?or user needs to change in device settings?

Comment: you need to change the device setting..permission dialog can not be created.