# Request User Permission Dialog Language is based on Android System Locale not APP Locale

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, user-permissions

I Used below codes for request permission from User, My OS Locale is not English but my APP Locale is English, Permission Dialog language came based on System Locale.How to change permission Locale based on APP.

**ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
permissionsNeededList.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);**

```
 public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
String[] APP_PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};

private boolean checkAndRequestPermission() {
    List<String> permissionsNeededList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String PERMISSION : APP_PERMISSIONS) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsNeededList.add(PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    if (!permissionsNeededList.isEmpty()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissionsNeededList.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is similar, check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034048/change-the-language-of-runtime-permission

Comment: Hey did you figure out ? @appukrb. I am facing same issue.